# Is it possible central header consisting of more than one row?

Tags: google-sheets

Before printing a google sheets file to `PDF`, it is possible to easily set header and footer.
But I did not suceeded in setting a "multi rows" central header. I mean, I would like that each page of the `PDF` file would have a central header consisting of more than one row of data. For example:

```
Name of the Company
Department
Office Number
Type of Document
```

Is it possible?

Thank you all for any tip.

Comment: There's no restriction upon the number or placement of data that you wish  to place in a google document or a google sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Google Sheet will normally print as header rows any rows that are "frozen", in the normal editing view.  So if you want to print the first four rows of the sheet as a header, select the fourth row, then View - Freeze - Up to current row(4), and the rows will be frozen when scrolling.  They will also repeat as a header when printing.

Let us know if that is what you want.  If not, please provide a sample sheet, and highlight the rows that you want to print, as a header on each page.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.